# Swift - Group elements of Array by value (2 by 2, 3 by 3, etc...)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

EDIT: I'm not asking a function to count an occurence. I'm asking a function to count an occurence **2 by 2**, **3 by 3**, **10 by 10**, etc... this is my problem

I have an array of scores, lets say:

```
[2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,8,8,8,9,10,10]
```

I would like to have a function that transform this `Array` into a `Dictionary [Int: Int]()` to have something like that:

```
func groupArrayBy(array: Array<Int>, coef: Int) -> Array<Int, Int>{
   // if coef = 2 -> 2 by 2, count occurence
   // Transform the array to:
   // [2: 3, 4: 5, 6: 2, 8: 4, 10: 2]
   // return Dictionary
}
```

(With coef = 3, it would be: `[2: 7, 5: 3, 8: 6]` -> 3 by 3)

I found nothing about that. Is it even possible ?

Comment: I have closed it as a duplicate. The requirement for coeficient is just a simple extension of counting everything (count ocurrences and then filter the result for values > coefficient).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but even if it seems simple fro you, I'm struggling with this part for many hours. Do I have to reopen a new question for that ? I tried to adapt the function but without success

Comment: @Sulthan, I do not think the requirement is simple enough as to be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Sulthan no this code is not working unfortunately

Comment: It seems I am not sure what the coefficient actually means. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I would like to group values by 2, or 3, or 10 or whatever number. if by 2: 2,3 / 4,5 / 6,7 / 8,9 ... If by 3: 2,3,4 / 5,6,7 / 8,9,10 ...

Comment: Maybe `coef` is not a good term to represent such grouping...

Comment: I'm sorry about that I'm not fluent I do my best to speak English

Comment: @KevinB This is really unclear. "by 2 or 3" doesn't really explain much at all. My best guess is that given coef = 3, you want to count the number of elements in the internal between `2..<4`, `5..<8`, `8..<11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version where I filter on a range based on first value of the array and the `coef` variable, based on the result I slice away those elements already counted and filter again on the smaller array in a loop. This solution requires the input array to be sorted in ascending order

```
func group(_ array: [Int], coef: Int) -> [Int: Int] {
    var result:[Int:Int] = [:]

    var start = array[0]
    var end = start + coef - 1
    var arr  = array

    while start <= array[array.count - 1] {
       let count = arr.filter({ $0 >= start && $0 <= end}).count

       result[start] = count
       start = end + 1
       end = start + coef - 1
       arr = Array(arr[count...])
    }
    return result
}
```

And here is a recursive version of the above function

```
func group(_ array: [Int], coef: Int) -> [Int: Int] {
    var result:[Int:Int] = [:]
    if array.isEmpty { return result }

    let end = array[0] + coef - 1
    let count = array.filter({ $0 >= array[0] && $0 <= end}).count
    result[array[0]] = count
    result = result.merging(group(Array(array[count...]), coef: coef)) { $1 }
    return result
}
```

Comment: `filter(predicate).count` is an anti-pattern. It allocates an intermediate array and copies all the passing elements, only to count them immediately discard them. Use `.count(where: predicate)` instead.

Comment: @Alexander Well I guess Swift is an anti-pattern then, at least it was when I wrote this answer because no count(where:) existed then and I am not sure it exists yet. Care to point me to some documentation?

Comment: Oh I thought [this was shipped already, but it's only been implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0220-count-where.md). (I have an extension in my projects that does the same thing). Nevermind, then you can resort to the previous best practice, of `array.lazy.filter(predicate).count`.

Answer (score 1):

I am still a bit confused about the coefficient. However, let's suppose that what you want is to group any value `N` with the next `N+coefficient` values.

Then I would start by remapping the original array into the group values:

```
let items = [2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,8,8,8,9,10,10]

let uniqueItems = Set(items)
var itemCoefficientMapping: [Int: Int] = [:]

let coefficient = 3
for item in uniqueItems.sorted() {
    // look whether exists some lower value that is not itself mapped to another value
    let normalizedItem = (item - (coefficient - 1)...item).first {
        uniqueItems.contains($0) && itemCoefficientMapping[$0] == $0
    } ?? item
    itemCoefficientMapping[item] = normalizedItem
}

// count  by mapped value
let counts: [Int: Int] = items.reduce(into: [:]) { result, value in
    result[itemCoefficientMapping[value] ?? value, default: 0] += 1
}

print(counts)
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for, thank you. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so confusing that what `coef` means or can we expect the input array is sorted, what output type you want. There's no `Array<Int, Int>` in Swift.

Assuming the input array is sorted and you want `Array<(Int, Int)>`, you can write something like this:

```
func getRanges(_ arr: [Int], _ step: Int) -> [Range<Int>] {
    return stride(from: arr.first!, through: arr.last!, by: step)
        .map {$0..<$0+step}
}
func groupArrayBy(array: Array<Int>, coef: Int) -> [(Int, Int)] {
    let grpArr = getRanges(arr, coef).map {rng in
        (rng.lowerBound, arr.lazy.filter{rng.contains($0)}.count)
    }
    return grpArr
}

print(groupArrayBy(array: arr, coef: 2)) //->[(2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 2), (8, 4), (10, 2)]
print(groupArrayBy(array: arr, coef: 3)) //->[(2, 7), (5, 3), (8, 6)]
```

My code is not so efficient and there may be someone who can show you more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

It may have another simpler code as this:

```
let aa : [Int] = [2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,6,8,8,8,9,10,10]
let mini = aa.min()!
let coeff : Int = 3

let dict = Dictionary(grouping: aa) {
mini + (($0 - mini) / coeff) * coeff
   }.mapValues{$0.count}

print (dict)
```